# routes.yaml - Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony

I just started with Symfony 4 (first experience with a framework) and I have a problem with routes.yaml
I was going on with the tutortial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sT4dMKSA1-A and couldn't make it work with setting up routes in that file routes.yaml

1)I created a page in templates folder hello_page.html.twig

2)Made changes in file routes.yaml

```
hello_page:
    path: /anything/
    controller: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\TemplateController::templateAction
    defaults:
        template: 'hello_page.html.twig'
```

3)Run command `C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project>php bin/console debug:router`

the error displayed:

```
2018-02-13T22:29:33+01:00 [error] Error thrown while running command "debug:router". Message: "The file "C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\config/routes.yaml" does not contain valid YAML in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\config/routes.yaml (which is loaded in resource "C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\config/routes.yaml")."

In FileLoader.php line 168:

  The file "C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\config/routes.yaml" does not contain valid YAML in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\
  config/routes.yaml (which is loaded in resource "C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\config/routes.yaml").


In YamlFileLoader.php line 63:

  The file "C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\config/routes.yaml" does not contain valid YAML.


In Parser.php line 158:

  A YAML file cannot contain tabs as indentation in "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\my_project\\config/routes.yaml" at line 4 (ne
  ar "  defaults:").
```

Any help much appreciated - regarding this problem or any advice related with Symfony 4

Comment: Open up you `routes.yaml` with either Notepad++ or any decent IDE and you will probably see tab indentations. Any decent IDE will replace your tabs with spaces automatically as well...

Comment: If this is your "(first experience with a framework)" why not do it the [Symfony 4 way](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html)? Step one install the annotations package. Annotate the routes right in the controller, and you only need to edit routes.yaml if you're importing routes from third party bundles.

Answer (score 1):

You obviously used tab in the routes.yaml in the 3rd line before "defaults:". Replace it with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use routes local in the controller files. When you create a reusable bundle it is a good practice to keep the routes separated but for a project you should keep your route in the controller. you can read more [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html) about the routes.